# How should we tag Rex: Last Days of an Empire questions?

Tags: discussion, tagging

I've got a Rex question, but [rex-final-days-of-an-empire](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rex-final-days-of-an-empire) is too long - what should we use as the tag?

Some possibilites would be [rex-final-days](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rex-final-days), [rex-final-days-empire](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rex-final-days-empire), and [rex-fdoae](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rex-fdoae). I used [rex-final-days-empire](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rex-final-days-empire) for the moment, for the sake of more recognizable words.

What's the verdict?

Answer (score 2):

I can't actually think of any reason not to use [rex](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rex), as there's nothing else out there similar enough to confuse with the tag at the moment.

[rex-final-days](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rex-final-days) or [rex-final-days-empire](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rex-final-days-empire) are OK but prolix; they don't actually add to the clarity of the game description.  [twilight-imperium-rex](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/twilight-imperium-rex) isn't discoverable enough.  (Although there might be an argument for [rex-twilight-imperium](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rex-twilight-imperium).  A similar issue could arise with the Android games at some point.)

Failing that, we could always use [dune](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dune). ;)

Comment: Aside: We can always synonym in the longer forms if there're signs of confusion.

Comment: Wait, so this is the republished Dune game? AWESOME!

Comment: @AlexP: Yep.  Those who don't know the Dune universe are unlikely to see anything in it, but the retheming to Twilight Imperium is *really* obvious if you do.  Even if you didn't play the original Dune game, for example, you can easily guess which TI faction represents which Dune unit.